# Should all the data in an object be loaded once it is created?

Tags: c#

Are there any best practices or guidelines when to load data in an object?

For example. You are working with a questionnaire. The questionnaire contains questions. The amount of the question can vary from 0 - 500. The questionnaire contains a method called `GetAllQuestions()`.

And this is my point. Is it recommended to create a member variable (let's say `_allQuestions` of type `Collection<Question>`) and fill that variable in the constructor? Code:

```
public class Questionnaire
{
  Collection<Question> _allQuestions;

  public Questionnaire()
  {
    _allQuestions = new Collection<Question>();

    LoadAllQuestions();
  }

  public Collection<Question> GetAllQuestions()
  {
    return _allQuestions;
  }

  private void LoadAllQuestions()
  {
    // Some database stuff and fill _allQuestions
  }
}
```

Or is it better to return all the questions at the moment there's a request. Code:

```
public class Questionnaire
{

  public Questionnaire()
  {  

  }

  public Collection<Question> LoadAllQuestions()
  {
    // Some database stuff
    // Create and fill an object with all the questions
    // return the object
  }

}
```

In the last case I see a disadventage. What if you call this method ten times? Then the database is accessed ten times for the same data. So in that case you can go for the first situation. But what if some questions are deleted or added? Then the list is inconsistent.

This is just an example. There are more situations when I wonder what to do. When should I load what data.

I was wondering, are there some guidelines or best practices when to load which data for an object?

Answer (score 4):

You can do both. Don't load anything when you create the object. Load the questions once, the first time they are requested, and cache them in a field for subsequent requests.

```
public class Questionnaire
{
  Collection<Question> _allQuestions;

  public Collection<Question> AllQuestions
  {
    get {
      if (_allQuestions == null)
        LoadAllQuestions();
      return _allQuestions;
    }
  }

  private void LoadAllQuestions()
  {
    _allQuestions = new Collection<Question>();
    // Some database stuff and fill _allQuestions
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds logical. But what to do when a question is deleted, added or modified?

Comment: @Martijn - could you make the code that deals with deleting, adding and modifying questions raise an event when that happens? Then the Quiestionnaire can watch that event and 'forget' it's questions (i.e., _allQuestions = null), so they'll get re-loaded the next time they're asked for.

Comment: @Martijn: That's the classic caching conundrum. You can expire the cached questions when they get past a certain age.

Comment: @IanR: I think that is possible. What I'd like to know is, is that a common/recommended approach? Is that according architectural disciplines?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a case where you need to be performing "[Lazy Loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)", that is only loading the information (in this case the questions) when you actually need them.

As you identified loading the questions in the constructor is hitting the database every time a `Questionnaire` object is created - an unnecessary overhead if you're not actually going to use the questions at *that time*.

The "rule" (if it can be called a rule) should be looking at the expense of loading the data verses it's utility. In some cases you are going to need all the data on creation, in others you aren't. It will depend on the data - which is hedging my bets I know, but that's all you can do with the "real world".

Answer (score 0):

It will all depends on how frequently your data is going to be loaded and if the data is going to be used. For example if you going to be using the questions in your questionnaire then it is best to load the complete object graph, but let's say that users would be looking at a list of questionnaires and only when they click on one to see the questions then it is better load those questions when you request the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the data you need. Implement paging of some kind  and retrieve the questions you need to show in the current page..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing two concepts.

At the completion of the constuctor, the object should be in a **valid** (usable) state.  However, that is not the same as having all data loaaded.

"Valid", in simple terms, could mean bascially, "All properties return correct values".  This could be handled by lazy loading as described in other answers.